# Backbone.js is not rendering views properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, node.js, backbone.js

I am new at ruby on rails and backbone as well. I have an existing code in backbone and ruby which is working fine which creates some boards and one board have many lists and so on. I will provide code for that one also if needed. Now I am going to add some feature of categories like user can create and delete categories and each categories have many boards. Following data is displayed on browser from Database which is correct. I am not getting it properly why proper views are not displaying on browser.

[image: Category Page]

Following is the code. Kindly suggest me some code changes so that it will     work. It will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> /app/assets/javascripts/collections/categories.js

```js
Kanban.Collections.Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Kanban.Models.Category,
  url: "/categories",
});
```

> app/assets/javascripts/models/category.js

```js
Kanban.Models.Category = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

  urlRoot: "/categories",

 relations: [{
  type: Backbone.HasMany,
  key: "boards",
  relatedModel: "Kanban.Models.Board",
  collectionType: "Kanban.Collections.Boards",
  reverseRelation: {
   key: "category"
  }
 }]

});
```

> app/assets/javascripts/views/categories/categories_index.js

```js
Kanban.Views.CategoriesIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: JST['categories/index'],
  tagName: "section",
  className: "categories-index",

  events: {
    "submit form.create_category": "createCategory"
  },

  initialize: function () {
    var that = this;
    that.collection.on("all", that.render, that);
  },

  render: function () {
    var that = this;

    var renderedContent = that.template({
      categories: that.collection
    });

    that.$el.html(renderedContent);

    console.log("categories ka render");
    return that;
  },

  createCategory: function (event) {
    event.defaultPrevented();
    var that = this;

    // get form attrs, reset form
    var $form = $(event.target);
    var attrs = $form.serializeJSON();
    $form[0].reset();

    var category = new Kanban.Models.Category();

    // fail if no category name
    if (!attrs.category.name) {
      var $createContainer = $("div.create_category");
      var $nameInput = that.$el.find("input.category_name");

      $nameInput.hide();
      $createContainer.effect("shake", {
        distance: 9,
        times: 2,
        complete: function () {
          $nameInput.show();
          $nameInput.focus();
        }
      }, 350);
      return false;
    }

    // save list
    category.save(attrs.category, {
      success: function (data) {
        // category.get("users").add(Kanban.currentUser);
        that.collection.add(category);

        // keep focus on list input
        that.$el.find("input.category_name").focus();
      }
    });
  }

});
```

> app/assets/javascripts/routers/main_routers.js

```js
Kanban.Routers.Main = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.$rootEl = options.$rootEl;
  },

  routes: {
    "": "index",
    "/login": "login",
    "categories/:id": "showCategoryBoards",
    "boards/:id": "showBoardLists"
    //"boards/:id": "deleteBoard"
  },

  index: function () {
    var that = this;

    var categoriesIndex = new Kanban.Views.CategoriesIndex({
      collection: Kanban.categories
    });
    
    that.$rootEl.html(categoriesIndex.render().$el);
  },



//index: function () {
    //var that = this;

    //var boardsIndex = new Kanban.Views.BoardsIndex({
      //collection: Kanban.boards
    //});
    
    //that.$rootEl.html(boardsIndex.render().$el);
  //},



  showCategoryBoards: function (id) {
    var that = this;

    var category = Kanban.categories.get(id);
    var categoryShow = new Kanban.Views.BoardIndex({
      model: category
    });

    that.$rootEl.html(categoryShow.render().$el);
  },



showBoardLists: function (id) {
    var that = this;

    var board = Kanban.boards.get(id);
    var boardShow = new Kanban.Views.BoardShow({
      model: board
    });

    that.$rootEl.html(boardShow.render().$el);
  }

});
```

> app/assets/javascripts/kanban.js

```js
window.Kanban = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  initialize: function() {
    var that = this;

    that.$rootEl = $("#content");

    Kanban.currentUser = new Kanban.Models.CurrentUser();
    Kanban.currentUser.fetch({
      success: function (response) {
          // console.log("got user");
          
        Kanban.category = new Kanban.Models.Category();
        Kanban.category.fetch({
          success: function (response) {   

            Kanban.boards = new Kanban.Collections.Boards();
            Kanban.boards.fetch({
              success: function (response) {
                // console.log("got boards");
                new Kanban.Routers.Main({ $rootEl: that.$rootEl });
                Backbone.history.start();

               }
             });
          },

          error: function (response) {
            // console.log("please log in");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  Kanban.initialize();


});


//BOARD DELETION METHOD... !
$(document).on("click", ".delete-icon", function() {
  var board_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/boards/"+board_id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
      $("#"+board_id).remove();
    }
  });
});

//LIST DELETION METHOD... !

$(document).on("click", ".list-delete-icon", function() {
  var listId = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace(/list_/, '');
  // alert(listId);
  //var id = $("div").attr('id').replace(/button/, '');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/lists/"+listId,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
      alert("success!!!");
      $("#list_"+listId).remove();
    }
  });
});

//card DELETION METHOD... !
```

> app/assets/templates/categories/index.jst.ejs

```html
<header class="categories-index">
  <span class=""></span>
  <h2>My Categories</h2>
</header>
<div>
<ul class="nav pull-left navbar-nav">
  <% categories.each(function (category) { %>
    <li id="<%= category.id %>" class="boxes">
      <a href="/#categories/<%= category.id %>">

        <%= category.escape("title") %>
      </a>
      
      <div class="delete-icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
      </div>

    </li>
  <% }); %>
<li class="boxes">
    <p>Create New Category</p>
    <form class="create_category" id="myform">
      <input type="text" 
             id="customInput"
             class="category_name"
             name="category[title]"
             placeholder="Category Name ..." />
      <input type="text"
             class="category_description"
             name="category[description]"
             placeholder="Category Description ..." />
      <input type="submit" value="Create Category" />
    </form>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

> /app/controllers/categories_controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :json

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    # respond_with(@categories)
    # @categories = current_user.categories.includes(:boards)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@category)
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
    respond_with(@category)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    category = Category.new(params[:category])

      if category.save

        # board.members << current_user
        render json: category, status: :ok
      else
        render json: category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
  end

  def update
    @category.update(category_params)
    respond_with(@category)
  end

  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_with(@category)
  end

  private
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

> app/models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description
    has_many :boards, dependent: :destroy
end
```

> app/views/categories/index.rabl

```
collection @categories
attributes :id, :title, :description
```

> config/routes.rb

```
Kanban::Application.routes.draw do



  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  # root to: "categories#index"  


  root to: "root#index"
  resource :root, only: [:index]

  resources :categories

#  resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
   #get "login" => "sessions#new"
  # get "logout" => "sessions#destroy"

  # resources :users, only: [:show]

  namespace :api do

    resources :users, only: [:show] do
      collection do
        get :current
      end
    end

    resources :boards, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]

    resources :lists , except: [:edit] do
      collection do
        post :sort
      end
    end

    resources :cards, except: [:edit] do
      collection do
        post :sort
      end
    end

    resources :card_comments, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to initialize a "collection" instead of a "model" in your **CategoriesIndex** file:

```
initialize: function () {
var that = this;
that.collection.on("all", that.render, that);
```

which is being called from your Route file calling constructor with **collection**.

```
index: function () {
var that = this;

var categoriesIndex = new Kanban.Views.CategoriesIndex({
  collection: Kanban.categories,

});

that.$rootEl.html(categoriesIndex.render().$el);
},
```

so, see your **kanban.js** file

it should be:

```
Kanban.categories = new Kanban.Collections.Categories();
Kanban.categories.fetch({
```